# hgsubversion reports old subversion version on Windows

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion

I am trying to convert a Subversion repository to a Mercurial repository using hgsubversion on Windows 7. After many other errors which I have resolved, I am now stuck with what seems to be an incorrect Subversion version being used.

When I try to `hg clone file:///C:/source/` I get the following error:

```
abort: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/source'
Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'
```

This seems to indicate that the Subversion repository is version 1.8+ (which it is), but my local subversion tools are of an older version.

And indeed, `hg version --svn` shows:

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.8)

...

hgsubversion: 691078c03ed9
Subversion: 1.6.16
bindings: SWIG
```

However `svn --version` shows:

```
svn, version 1.8.4 (r1534716)
compiled Oct 28 2013, 05:30:01 on x86_64/x86-microsoft-windows5.1.2600
```

Why does hgsubversion report an older version of Subversion being used? As far as I know I only have Subversion 1.8.4 installed.

Or is this because of the bundled SWIG bindings that came with TortoiseHg? Should I try some other bindings?

Trying to get this to work has been a really frustrating experience so far.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is, that you have two different SVN Versions on your computer: your regular server svn, and the version bundled with hgsubversion. You can resolve this issue by

- Setting up a SVN server (I read that there should be a svnserve which can [run as windows service](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking.winservice)), so that hgsubversion talk to your SVN-repo by the version agnostic wire protocoll
- dump your repo content, and load it into a newly created repo, which is created with `svnadmin --pre-1.7-compatible`, so that the hgsubversion version can read it

Comment: There's an SVN version bundled with hgsubversion?

Thank you for your answer, however, I decided to give up trying to get the conversion working on Windows. Instead I installed Ubuntu inside Virtualbox and did the conversion succesfully there. :)

Comment: Having this problem myself, three years later. The pre compatible flag isn't recognized when I run svnadmin.

Comment: @DCShannon perhaps you could do the conversion inside a Linux VM like I did? From what I can remember it went very smoothly compared to the experience on Windows 7.